# when saving canvas image server-side, from a base64 data string,it produce blank image

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, canvas

I have problem with saving canvas image in PHP. I get a blank `.png` file. I search a lot about this problem but cant find anything useful about this. Why does it save a blank image instead of rendering real image?

JavaScript code:

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('dadycool')], {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL();
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('imagec').appendChild(image);
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "up.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: data
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  console.log('saved'); 
}); 
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
// requires php5
define('localhost/samp/sample2/uploads', 'images/');
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = localhost/samp/sample2/uploads . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Comment: By default, as far I as know, toDataUrl returns png image,`$img = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $img);` should be `$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);`

Comment: yes right!! I forgot to wrote the update version of my code :D but my problem still exist.

Comment: You can replace the PHP part with [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload) and its [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/d0065c47dcda18c4965ed900bb15190f7af30e79/src/DataUriUpload.php) component, as [documented here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/d0065c47dcda18c4965ed900bb15190f7af30e79#data-uri-uploads). It does take care of other things, such as file size limitations and multiple accepted MIME types, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't configured your development box to display PHP error messages. You are defining a constant that is not a valid identifier:

```
define('localhost/samp/sample2/uploads', 'images/');
```

That means that you cannot use it directly:

```
$file = localhost/samp/sample2/uploads . uniqid() . '.png';
```

... should be triggering:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost'
Notice: Use of undefined constant samp - assumed 'samp'
Warning: Division by zero
Notice: Use of undefined constant sample2
Warning: Division by zero
Notice: Use of undefined constant uploads - assumed 'uploads'
Warning: Division by zero
```

... and `file` will only contain the base file name (e.g. `53676a01cdb59.png`) but not path component. You need to use this syntax:

```
$file = constant('localhost/samp/sample2/uploads') . uniqid() . '.png';
```

... or, even better, give the constant a sensible name:

```
define('DIR_UPLOADS', 'images/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue - it looked like the base64 data was being sent correctly but always failed to generate the image server side. The solution I found was to use the 'FormData' object and a very simple xhr request to post to the server.

```
var url='/path/to/save.php';
var data=oCanvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '');
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append('imgdata',data);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url);
request.send(fd);
```

I'm 99% sure the problem was caused by the incorrect Content-Type header being sent by the xhr request. Using a basic xhr request combined with FormData forced the xhr request to be sent with the multipart/formdata content type with correctly defined content boundaries.